# Index was outside the bounds of the array . But All arrays are correct

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Hello i'm getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" if i'm putting value **(i) in itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[i].ToString())**

```
object[] itemDetails;
object[] itemLis = itemsWS.searchItem("", "bread", "all");
int xs = 35;
int clefts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < itemLis.Length; i++)

{
    itemDetails = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[i].ToString());
    Button myButtons = new Button();
    myButtons.Click += delegate
    {

        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 11;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Item Code";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Description";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Sale Price";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Category";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Type";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Status";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Low Count";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Medium Count";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "High Count";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Item Picture";
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = "TEST";

        //here is where i'm getting error if i put i on the []

        itemDetails = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[i].ToString());

        //

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(itemDetails);
        MessageBox.Show("data grid displayed!");

    };


    myButtons.Text = itemDetails[1].ToString() + "\n  " + itemDetails[2].ToString();
    myButtons.Top = cleft * 180;
    myButtons.Left = 70;
    myButtons.Location = new Point(xs, clefts);
    myButtons.Size = new Size(100, 60);
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(myButtons);
    xs += 135;

    if (xs >= 537)
    {
        xs = 35;
        clefts += 80;
    }
```

(this is the database)

[image]

The problem is if I replace [i] with [0]. It will only display the first value item in the database

(here is the GUI if i replaced [i] with [0]) Any button clicked would repeat the same output

[image]

Please any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to display items from MySQL using new buttons which was generated that would be displayed on the datagridview. Thanks

Note : that **itemsWS** is a web service coming from

> private KPWSItems itemsWS = new KPWSItems();

Comment: Can you see inner exception?

Comment: On which iteration exception thrown? Can you try foreach loop instead of for, as `foreach(var item in itemLis) { //... }`

Comment: Just store each itemDetails on an array, store the index on each button Tag. Inside the delegate just retrieve from the array with the index stored in its Tag

Comment: @X-TECH . I tried foreach but still out of bounds

Comment: what if I tried adding another again. will I store another array programmatically? @Martheen

Comment: Why do you have to add this line code twice `itemDetails = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[i].ToString());` I think the one in the top is enough, so you don't have to call it again (where you get the error).

Comment: If you add other by calling the appropriate web service, and re-load them back from the web service, sure

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan you are right!. my bad.. but if i tried removing it.. it will only display the last item on my database which is sample6 item

Comment: Are you using soap service? If yes then clean project, update its reference and then try again

Comment: @X-TECH still out of bounds. " An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'  "

Comment: I think it's not related (about calling it twice and only display the last item) And about `myButtons`, can't you specified ID (let's say "mybutton"+i) to become the ID to distinguished a button from another?

Comment: I can @HeinzSiahaan. But what if I add another item.. Will I add new code for the new buttons?.. the new buttons should be dynamic that automatically displays on the tabcontrol and gets the value from mySQL and should be displayed at the datagridview when i clicked the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemLis.Length; i++)
{
    itemDetails = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[i].ToString());
    Button myButtons = new Button();
    //myButtons.Tag = i;
    myButtons.Tag = itemDetails;
    myButtons.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
         var button = sender as Button;
         dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 11;
         dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Item Code";
         dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Description";
         dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Sale Price";
         dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Category";
         dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Type";
         dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Status";
         dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Low Count";
         dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Medium Count";
         dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "High Count";
         dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Item Picture";
         dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = "TEST";

         //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLis[(int)button.Tag].ToString())
         dataGridView1.Rows.Add((object[])button.Tag));

         MessageBox.Show("data grid displayed!");
    };


    myButtons.Text = itemDetails[1].ToString() + "\n  " + itemDetails[2].ToString();
    myButtons.Top = cleft * 180;
    myButtons.Left = 70;
    myButtons.Location = new Point(xs, clefts);
    myButtons.Size = new Size(100, 60);
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(myButtons);
    xs += 135;

    if (xs >= 537)
    {
       xs = 35;
       clefts += 80;
    }
```

Comment: This code displays all of my items (sample1 - sample6) in a single click of any button

Comment: It's because you have this line `for (int j = 0; j < itemLis.Length; i++)
         {` and when you remove  it, it's the same with OP code

Comment: @X-TECH when removing " dataGridView1.Rows.Add(itemDetails); ".. It turns to an empty infinite loop in the datagridview and the screen will freeze

Comment: Still, I don't get the idea, why you must get data from web service twice (when you already retrieve the data before) ?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan You are right, it can be solve to put data into button tag, instead of `i`

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo Please try my edit again. If its working then use it.

Comment: Hi @X-TECH your code before is working perfectly for me. Cheers!